# Finding Dynamically added Checkbox inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have added checkboxes inside gridview dynamically on page load event.i want to save unchecked checkboxes value inside database,but i am not getting dynamically added checkbox control's value it always returns null value.

Code sample:

```
CheckBox chkQtyval1 = (CheckBox)gv.Rows[index].Cells[i].FindControl("chkCheckBox");
```

it's returning a null value.

The code behind:

Thanks in advance

Comment: cab you update the question with code where you add the controls ?

Answer (score 0):

each dynamically added checkbox will have an autoassigned ID.

So, Assuming your in a for loop when adding the checkboxes....
When you create the Checkboxes you add an .ClientID = x;

Then when you want to get the control use

```
CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)Use Gridview.Findcontrol(x);
if(chkbox!=null)
{
//Do Something
}
```

Where 'x' is the value that was assigned to the checkbox ID when you created it.

Note: Find control can be flaky, so here's one we use that works by looping over the whole control tree (or just part of it) until it finds a match.

```
public Static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
      if (root.ID == id)
    {
    return root;
    }

      foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
    {
    Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
    if (t != null)
      {
       return t;
      }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Control root can be Page, Master or Control (ike GridView)

2nd Note: this is marked as Static, so you use it as Class.FindControlRecursive()
or remove the static reference completely to use it in a single page only